# Create switcher on top swift?

Tags: swift

I wanted to create a switcher that picture.I tried so but couldn't find the answer to that.

like this "About","Rooms" and "Reviews"

You can guide how to do it ?

thanks

https://i.stack.imgur.com/91tzY.jpg

Comment: You can either customize a `UISegmentedControl`, roll your own from scratch, or choose one of the [many open source ones](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/search?q=tabs)

Comment: Or maybe a UITabBarController?

Comment: That looks like a tab bar controller. Look at UITabBarController

Comment: tab bar is not top